# Angular 2 MVC Subscribe function with timer still calling method after unsubscribe

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, timer, subscribe

Hi I am testing how to use a timer use a subscribe to run a function within a time frame. The problem I am having is that once I unsubscribe and change component the method is till getting called. I would like to know how to stop it. this is my code:

`

```
    import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { Headers, Http } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/Rx";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

// Variables that load the respectively JavasScript methods in the JavaScript file SharedContents/plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.js
declare var initRealTimeChart: any;
declare var initSparkline: any;
declare var initDonutChart: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: require('./home.component.html')
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy  {

    _message: string;
    foo;
    private subscriptions: Array<Subscription> = [];

    //called first time before the ngOnInit()
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    //called after the constructor and called  after the first ngOnChanges() 
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._message = "adsad";
        console.log(this._message);
        //setInterval(() => this.getLog("Home/GetTest"), 500);

        this.subscriptions.push(this.getLog("Home/GetTest").subscribe(
            response => {
                console.log('Success ' + response);
            },
            err => {
                console.log('Error' + err)
            },
            () => {
                console.log('Complete')
            }
        ));


    }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {

    }

    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {

    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        initRealTimeChart();
        initSparkline();
        initDonutChart();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {

        console.log("ngOnDestroy!");

        this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription: Subscription) => {
            console.log("Destroying Subscription :", subscription);
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        });
    }

    public TestStuff() {

        console.log("Run TestTSuff");

        return this.http.get("Home/GetTest")
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
                response.json().data;
                console.log('GOT IT!');
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch((ex) => {
                console.log(ex);
                console.log(ex._body);
            });
    }

    getLog(url: string): Observable<string> {
        return Observable
            .timer(0, 12000)
            .concatMap(() => this.get(url))
            ///.retryWhen(error => error.delay(12000))
            .map((data: any) => {
                console.log('Request Success!')
                data.json();
                return data.json();
            })
            .catch(e => {
                //console.warn(e.toString());
                return Observable.from("ERROR" + e);
            });
    }

    get(url) {
        return this.http.get(url);
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue.

All I needed was to clear the browsing cache.

Thanks for all the help anyway.